# OpenVPN routing between two separate network

Tags: centos, iptables, openvpn

I've set-up an OpenVPN server on CentOS, it is working and I can connect to it from clients without problem. Now I'm trying to edit iptable config in order to access to my LAN from VPN clients, but i'm not able.

The VPN server IP is 10.10.10.14, in a 10.10.10.0/24 mask.
The LAN mask is 10.10.0.0/21.
The mask of VPN client device is 192.168.200.0/21.

Between network I have a physical firewall that is now temporary disabled. Someone could suggest me a solution or a starting point to find the solution myself? Iptable is already installed and running.

---

Searching on Google I've found this iptable role, to allow clients to access the VPN server (it works):

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.200.024 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

I've tried to modify it  like:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.021 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

but it doesn't work and I don't really understand the meaning.

---

Port forwarding is enebled `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in sysctl file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, your VPN server IP and the LAN overlap (10.10.10.14/24 is *inside* 10.10.0.0/21), so that's likely to cause some issues.

Comment: The two LAN are electrically separated (two different port of firewall). Also the 10.10.0.0/21 LAN is from 10.10.0.1 to 10.10.7.254.

Comment: I made some tests that are random (in my opinion), I don't really know what I have to do. Maybe if you could explain with technical word what I have to do I can make some more useful tests.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess I fat-fingered my subnet calculation. In any event, the question of what you've tried still stands.

Comment: added an attempt